# Button and ImageView not working well together?

Tags: android

This is perhaps a very simple error, but I can't find it! It want to close the application at start if I have the ImageView before the Button in the layout! But not if I have the Button first and then the ImageView!? What could be the reason for this? I have pasted some of the code and hope that could tell what the error is? Preciate the help! Thanks!

Activity:

```
public class Activity_1 extends Activity {

ImageView imageView;

public final static String test ="Hello";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);


    Button btnImageMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartActivity_2);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);

    registerForContextMenu(imageView);

    // Button to open activity with gridview
    btnImageMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent("com.test.ACTIVITY_2"); // Alternative
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });
}

// Create context menu
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options for this menu"); // Title for the menu
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_1_menu, menu);
}

// Handle selected items from context menu
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    // Open activity with gridview of thumbnails
    case R.id.menu_option_1:
        // Toast.makeText(Activity_1.this, "" + "Menu option 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Activate activity 3 with listview of contacts
        Intent i = new Intent("com.test.ACTIVITY_3"); // Alternative
        startActivityForResult(i, 2);

        return true;

        // Open activity with listview of contacts
    case R.id.menu_option_2:
        Toast.makeText(Activity_1.this, "" + "Menu option 2",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

// Handle return values from different activities
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            String imageId = data.getExtras().getString("imageId");

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageId);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        else if(requestCode == 2) {
            String contact1 = data.getExtras().getString("contactName");
            String contact2 = data.getExtras().getString("test");
            Toast.makeText(Activity_1.this, "" + "Value from activity 3: " + contact1 + " " + contact2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnStartActivity_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnStartActivity_2" />
```

Error log:

```
02-24 20:34:50.945: I/ApplicationPackageManager(13296): cscCountry is not German : NEE
02-24 20:34:50.976: D/AndroidRuntime(13296): Shutting down VM
02-24 20:34:50.984: W/dalvikvm(13296): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.assignment.two/com.test.assignment.two.Activity_1}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at com.test.assignment.two.Activity_1.onCreate(Activity_1.java:31)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-24 20:34:51.000: E/AndroidRuntime(13296):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: sorry but I am unable to understand your question..is this your problem that when imageview followed by button closing your application or is this your requirement.

Comment: I think it's a layout thing. If the XML code for the Button comes first in layout it's OK, but if the XML code for the ImageView comes first the application crash from the beginning without me doing nothing!? Was this a little bit more helpful?

Comment: show stack trace, as i don't see any issue with the current posted code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is no error.. try this:

Set Image for Imageview using android:src="yourimage"

Project >> Clean

This will clean your project and rebuild the classes. Hope this solves your problem.